# How to set ik-analyzer as the default analyzer of index in solr of wso2?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I got wso2am-4.0.0 and deployed on my vm. I added some  api with chinese name or businessowner name etc. I tried to query by content from devportal like '天气', but nothing listed. I guess chinese data in solr had no support by default. How to achive this ?